# CloudKit: creatorUserRecordID of CKRecord Issue (or Bug?)

Tags: ios, cloudkit

After iOS 8.3, if the record is created by the current account, its creatorUserRecordID will be like

> CKRecordID: [Some Address]; **defaultOwner**:(_defaultZone:**defaultOwner**)

And then if fetch this recordID using fetchRecordWithID:completionHandler: from CKDatabase, it will always return error like

> CKError [Some Address]: "Unknown Item" (11/2003); server message = "Record not found"; uuid = [Some UUID]; container ID = [Some Container ID]

I never encounter this issue before.

Is it a bug, or should I fetch record from recordID like this ( **defaultOwner** ) in other way?

**EDIT (add sample code)**

```
- (void)postMoodFeed:(NSString *)moodFeed
{
    CKRecord *moodRecord = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Mood"];
    moodRecord[@"moodFeed"] = moodFeed

    [[[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase] saveRecord:moodRecord completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
        [self queryMyMood];
    }];
}

- (void)queryMyMood
{
    // currentUserRecordID is fetched from fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler: of CKContainer
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"creatorUserRecordID = %@", currentUserRecordID];

    CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Mood" predicate:predicate];

    [[[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase] performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
        if (results) {
            for (CKRecord *eachRecord in results) {
                // Following logs are all __defaultOwner__
                NSLog(@"%@", eachRecord.creatorUserRecordID.recordName);
                [[[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase]fetchRecordWithID:eachRecord.creatorUserRecordID completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
                    // All following logs are "Unknown item" error
                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

**EDIT** July 2, 2015

That is a bug.

After reporting to Apple, they fixed this issue in iOS 9 Beta 2.

Comment: Did it work before? Did you reset the database in the CloudKit dashboard recently? If so, did you check the query for ID on the User recordType?

Comment: 1. Same code worked before ( I don't change any line. )

2. Yes, I tried resetting database (development environment)

3. You mean query __defaultOwner__ recordID for Users record type? I'll try.

Comment: Then it should just work. Can you show us the code how you first read the record and then the userRecord? One other thing. It's not advised to base your app on the functionality of the defaultOwner field. If you ever decide to migrate your data to a different structure, and use an app to do that, then all new records will be in the database with a defaultOwner of the process that did the migration. Besides that you should also not use the User recordType because it's a special recordType with limited functionality. Create your own user recordType instead.

Comment: If there is a record "Feed" created by user, next time I fetch this Feed record, and I'll find that the recordName of this Feed's creatorUserRecordID is __defaultOwner__. Then fetch it, it comes error.

Comment: It never happened until last weekend (I just updated to iOS 8.3 and Xcode 6.3). And I found that the recordName of creatorUserRecordID was the correct unique name of that user record, not __defaultOwner__ before.

Comment: can you show us the code?

Comment: Edwin, I just update the sample code on original post, please kindly review it.

Comment: first tip: public database does not work with zone's just leave it nil instead of self.publicZone.zoneID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75161/discussion-between-ananfang-and-edwin-vermeer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it looks like new functionality.

What you could do is first testing if the eachRecord.creatorUserRecordID.recordName == "**defaultOwner**" and if that's the case you could fetch the record for the ID that you got from the currentUserRecordID

But it would be better to not use the creatorUserRecordID for any functionality in your app. You could better add a new CKReference field and always fill it with the currentUserRecordID. Then even if you have a process that migrates data, you would still know who created that record originally.

Comment: I agree, sometimes weird how `creatorUserRecordID` works, better to download records by `CKReference` than `creatorUserRecordID`, in my case it might not download all the records

Comment: Hi Edwin, Could you give me information about the CKReference field.
Lets say I have a record type "Notes". You say that it is beeter to add a new CKReference filed to this type. OK, With what RecordID should be created that Reference - with the RecordID of the creator or I am wrong. Should I add CKReferenceActionDeleteSelt or not?

Comment: @ivan A CKReference will contain a RecordID which defines the relation plus an action (None or DeleteSelf). So for instance an Order record will have a CKReference to a Client. Set it to DeleteSelf if you want the order to be deleted if the client is deleted. For more information see https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKReference_class/index.html

Comment: Ah, you updated your question... Yes, i meant the recordId of the creator. Adding DeleteSelf depends on the functionality that you want.

Comment: In your first comment to me you are pointing to have a two records types The second one with the references to point to the first one. Am I right? As my first record (Notes) contain a lat/long I would like to get records for the x radius near me using predicate no matter if records belongs to me or not and after that to evaluate which one is mine. Because of that I am not sure how to organize the CKReference field

Comment: If your predicate to the Notes is working for the items near you, then you could extend that predicate to also filter for the CKReference. You could also filter the Note's after you have read them all. Which of these 2 options you use depends on if you need the Notes from other people or not.

Comment: Is that mean that I have to fetchUserRecrdID (the ID of the creator) every time when I need to add a new Note record. As the CKReference have be to initiated with the RecordID of the creator?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: I've found that if you use [CKFetchRecordsOperation fetchCurrentUserRecordOperation] at the beginning of your app's workflow you won't have **defaultOwner** CKRecordIDs come out of nowhere.

Comment: After reporting to Apple, they fixed this issue in iOS 9 Beta 2 :)